# How to move all contents of one directory to new directory using wildcard?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, terminal, mv

I just updated my file structure for my website and trying to find a fast way to move all files into the new setup. The old set up was:

```
/CO/001/2022/02-18
/CO/002/2022/02-18
...
/CO/999/2022/02-18
```

Currently all my images are in that last 02-18 folder. I just updated things so that the new directory listing is:

```
/CO/001/2022-02-18
/CO/002/2022-02-18
...
/CO/999/2022-02-18
```

The problem is, I want to move everything I had in the old file structure folders (CO/*/2022/02-18) into the new folders (CO/*/2022-02-18) without having to manually go through all 999 old folders and dump the content into the new folders.

I tried the following command already:

```
mv */2022/02-19 */2022-02-19
```

But that doesn't seem to be working how intended and gave me a "will not overwrite just-created" error and was trying to put files into the wrong folder (images in 001/2022/02-18 were trying to be put into 002/2022-02-18 instead of 001/2022-02-18)

Comment: There is a powerful `rename`command that will be able to do this for you. It uses regalar expressions to rename files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We cannot make use of the wild card expansion because

```
mv */2022/02-18 */2022-02-18
```

will be expanded as:

```
mv 001/2022/02-18 002/2022/02-18 ... 999/2022/02-18 "*/2022-02-18"
```

which will not work as you might expect.
Would you please try instead:

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in /CO/*/2022/02-18/; do          # loop over the old directories
    if [[ -d $d ]]; then                # make sure $d is a dirname
        new=$(sed -E 's#([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}/)$#\1-\2#' <<< "$d")
                                        # modify "*/2022/02-18/" to "*/2022-02-18/"
        echo mv -- "$d" "$new"          # rename the dirname
        old=${d%/}; old=${old%/*}       # extract the parent directory name "*/2022"
        echo rmdir -- "$old"            # remove the empty parent directory
    fi
done
```

It just prints the commands which will be executed as a dry run. If the result
looks good, drop `echo` before `mv` and `rmdir` then run again. (Please note the dry run will output thousands of lines. You do not have to check all
the lines. Just looking over a few lines will be good enough.)